# Groupings Expanded

Tags: list

I'd like to be able to keep groupings expanded without needing to expand them each time.  That is, I want the expanded groupings to be the default when a user opens the page.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your view and in the "Group By" section, select the Expanded option for this property : "By default, show groupings:"

[image]